# Want to overwrite minicart/item/default.html file for minicart?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to hide qty box and remove/delete icon from mini cart for few products. For this I overwrite checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_Module/minicart/item/default</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then create default.html file under 
Custom/Module/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

But after doing this I found minicart is blank. like below image.
Can you please help me to understand my mistake?

[image: Mini Cart]

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Add **requirejs-config.js** in the following path

> app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

then add the below code in it

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/details.html':
            'Custom_Module/template/minicart/item/default.html'
    }

}};
```

then copy the file from

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

to

> app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

and run below comments in you magento root after made these changes

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: means I need to add require-config.js with my existing code or I need to remove layout file?

Comment: Remove the checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml from your custom module then do the above things and it will help you

Comment: after doing this mini cart not showing product correctly, I added two product in the cart but mini cart display only one product. The count is perfect but displays only one product. I need to overwrite some other file or not for this, Please help me.

Comment: In the cart page two product showing perfectly but not in minicart.

Comment: Right now all products are showing after running the command. I want to hide qty box and remove icon in cart page and I can see my code under pub/static folder in my module. But in mini cart section, it is not reflected. Below are my code
<!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility --> <!-- /ko -->
This I need to add before  qty box and remove icon [This is used for edit button, I copied this condition and add before qty and remove icon section]

Comment: I can see my code under pub/static but when I inspect in browser not able to see my code.

Comment: If you find this answer useful please do upvote and accept it. So other will get use to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90656/discussion-between-prathap-gunasekaran-and-nilava-chakraborty).

Comment: Sorry to say but Still I am facing issue with this approach. Still, my code is not working.

Comment: is \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem linked with Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/details.html
can i add a new value to the return 
e.g before 'options' => $this->getOptionList(), can i add 'enabled' => '1'
and call this in html 
< !-- ko if: enabled == 1  -- >
< h1 > test </ h1>
and finish the if for knockoutjs